# Using SOAP UI Test Suite, is it possible to use comparison operators when asserting a JSON response?

Tags: soapui

Let's say my api returns a JSON with the following:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "exception": "ERROR"
}
```

I want the SOAP UI test assertion to assert that this exception key should not be "ERROR". I am looking for a functionality within the soap ui testing suite similar to Junit's assertNotEqual.

The JsonPath Match assertion does not have the functionality to use comparison operators as far as I have seen.

Is there a straightforward way to use logic/comparison operators with SOAP UI assertions?

Comment: Use Script Assertion for the rest test step.